# How can I get a Distinct for each part of a pair Identifier

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table that allocates a Truck to a User, using their Identities to link each allocation to their respective entities.  Only the last allocation for a Truck/User can be selected.  I used the following LINQ to get the values I need

```
var query = (from ta in TruckAllocations
         where ta.Truck.Name != null || !ta.Truck.Name.Contains(string.Empty)
         group ta by  ta.UserId into grp
         let MaxDate = grp.Max(g => g.CreatedOn)
         from g in grp
         where g.CreatedOn == MaxDate
         select new { Key = g.TruckAllocationId, Truck = g.TruckId, User = g.UserId, Date = g.CreatedOn });
```

The problem I'm having is that two User's that are allocated to the same truck are in the result of the query, and I just want the last on assigned.  Example of result

```
47      26  224 2014-03-28 10:47 AM
48      3   149 2014-03-31 10:25 AM
1048    2   575 2014-04-04 1:14 PM
1049    23  575 2014-04-09 9:15 AM
1050    56  322 2014-04-09 2:27 PM
```

As you can see User [2 and 23] are assigned the same Truck [575]

the result that I want would be this:

```
47      26  224 2014-03-28 10:47 AM
48      3   149 2014-03-31 10:25 AM
1049    23  575 2014-04-09 9:15 AM
1050    56  322 2014-04-09 2:27 PM
```

Where record 1048, doesn't show because he was not the last User assigned to the Truck.

Is there a way to get a Distinct on the pair where each value in the pair has to be unique

**UPDATE**

I also tried

```
var query = (from ta in TruckAllocations
         where ta.Truck.Name != null || !ta.Truck.Name.Contains(string.Empty)
         group ta by  ta.TruckId into grp
         let MaxDate = grp.Max(g => g.CreatedOn)
         from g in grp
         where g.CreatedOn == MaxDate
         select new { Key = g.TruckAllocationId, Truck = g.TruckId, User = g.UserId, Date = g.CreatedOn });
```

Result is:

```
    6        54 3   2014-03-04 7:03 PM
    8        63 4   2014-03-13 12:36 PM
    10      626 4   2014-03-13 2:10 PM
    13       12 4   2014-03-20 4:18 PM
    21        8 3   2014-03-20 6:21 PM
    42       10 3   2014-03-21 1:09 PM
    43        3 26  2014-03-26 5:35 PM
    44       32 1   2014-03-27 8:53 AM
    47      224 26  2014-03-28 10:47 AM
    48      149 3   2014-03-31 10:25 AM
    1049    575 23  2014-04-09 9:15 AM
    1050    322 56  2014-04-09 2:27 PM
```

It does give me only one Truck/User for the Truck as the record [1048] is not returned, but now I have Use 4,3, 26 assigned to multiple trucks, when they can only be assigned one

And grouping with TruckId and UserId will add the Truck assigned to two Users, to the one grouped by TruckId.

```
var query = (from ta in TruckAllocations
         where ta.Truck.Name != null || !ta.Truck.Name.Contains(string.Empty)
         group ta by  new {ta.TruckId, ta.UserId} into grp
         let MaxDate = grp.Max(g => g.CreatedOn)
         from g in grp
         where g.CreatedOn == MaxDate
         select new { Key = g.TruckAllocationId, Truck = g.TruckId, User = g.UserId, Date = g.CreatedOn });
```

** UPDATE2 **

The solution that got me what I wanted was to query the table grouped by UserId (1st query in question), then query the table grouped by the TruckId (2nd query in question).  Then query both results to get matches on truck and user like this:

```
var assigned = (from t1 in query1
               from t2 in query2
               where t1.Truck == t2.Truck && t1.User == t2.User
               select new {t1.Key, t1.Truck, t1.User, t1.Date}).ToList();
```

Would like to know if there was a better way to do it though.

Comment: Well, more complicated than it looks. Let's imagine : All trucks used by User 1 have been used later by another User => User 1 should not appear in list, right ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like that (group, order by descending on the wanted element).

More used to fluent syntax, so...

```
var result = TruckAllocations
                .Where(ta => ta.Truck.Name != null && ta.Truck.Name != string.Empty)
                .GroupBy(ta => ta.UserId)
                //take the first element of each group, which will be the one with the max CreatedOn date
                .Select(g=> g.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedOn).First())
                .Select(m => new {
                   Key = m.TruckAllocationId, 
                   Truck = m.TruckId, 
                   User = m.UserId, 
                   Date = m.CreatedOn  
                });
```

**EDIT**

You may do this in one or two steps.

*CAUTION* : If all trucks used by a given user have been used later by another User => this User won't appear in list.

2 steps version

```
var lastDateByTruck = TruckAllocations
                    .Where(ta => ta.Truck.Name != null && ta.Truck.Name != string.Empty)
                    .GroupBy(m => m.TruckId)
                                   .Select(m => new
                                   {
                                       TruckId = m.Key,
                                       CreatedOn = m.Max(x => x.CreatedOn)
                                   });

var result = from allocation in TruckAllocations
                         join lastUsage in lastDateByTruck on new
                         {
                             allocation.TruckId,
                             allocation.CreatedOn
                         } equals new
                         {
                             lastUsage.TruckId,
                             lastUsage.CreatedOn
                         }
                         group allocation by allocation.UserId
                         into g
                         select new
                         {
                             UserId = g.Key,
                             TruckId = g.First().TruckId,
                             CreatedOn = g.First().CreatedOn

                         };
```

All in one with fluent syntax :

```
var lastDateByTruck = TruckAllocations
                       .Where(ta => ta.Truck.Name != null && ta.Truck.Name != string.Empty)
                       .GroupBy(m => m.TruckId)
                       .Select(m => new
                       {
                           TruckId = m.Key,
                           CreatedOn = m.Max(x => x.CreatedOn)
                       })
                       .Join(TruckAllocations, x => new{x.TruckId, x.CreatedOn}, y => new{y.TruckId, y.CreatedOn}, (x, y) => y)
                       .GroupBy(m => m.UserId)
                       .Select(g => new
                       {
                           UserId = g.Key,
                           TruckId = g.First().TruckId,
                           CreatedOn = g.First().CreatedOn
                       });
```

Comment: I tried your query, but with Lambda you can't use string.IsNullOrEmpty(), or I don't know how.  This query gives the same result as mine, with the same truck allocated to two users.

Comment: `with Lambda` ? You mean with linq to entities ?

Comment: Sorry, yes it's late and I work tomorrow morning, been trying to get this working.

Comment: Yes, and I think I understand the error, will try to correct.

Comment: @CheGueVerra see edit, maybe just a group by TruckId instead of UserId should be fine. At least with the sample given...

Comment: @CheGueVerra but this will mean that a UserId can appear twice (or more) in the resultset, if he's the last one to have used more than one truck... This case doesn't appear in your sample, so hard to know how you wanna manage it !

Comment: @Rapheal, the sample was a reduced to show the problem I was facing.  I did try grouping by TruckId, but that gives me the same User with all the trucks he was associated with, see Update

Comment: The query has to return an Unique TruckId and Unique UserId pairing, So if User A gets assigned truck 1 at 8am, and User B gets assigned Truck 1 at noon, the query should only return User B/Truck 1 pairing

Comment: don't worry I simplified my sample to much, which caused confusion.  I'm off to bed, will check your update in about 5 hours, thanks for the help